# preg_match Слэши

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, есть фрагмент кода:

```
if (preg_match("/[\\\\|/]/ui", $cellValues)) { //Проверка на слэши

            echo "<br>2 Пропущена позиция", $row_position, "<br>"; 
            $row_position = $row_position+1; //переходим на след строку, если слэши есть

        }
```

Мне необходимо отсеивать все записи, содержащие бэкслэш, вертикальный и обычный. Регулярное выражение в коде работает на сайте http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/li3 , но на практике выбивает ошибку:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ']'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Comment: в шаблоне у вас не хватает экранирующего слэша перед этим `/`. Вот так должно работать: `'/[\\\|\/]+/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярные выражения в PHP необходимо использовать внутри [**разделителей**](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Это либо парные символы (кавычки, скобки), либо какой-нибудь символ (часто используют обратный слеш, так как только этот символ используется в JavaScript, и многие к нему привыкли).

Если в шаблоне встречается символ, совпадающий с символом-разделителем, его необходимо экранировать. Если есть возможность, используйте такой символ в качестве разделителя, который не встречается в выражении.

Подойдут такие выражения:

```
"/[\\\\|\/]/"
"~[\\\\|/]~"
"#[\\\\|/]#"
"@[\\\\|/]@"
```

И так далее. Модификатор `i` здесь не требуется, так как в выражении нет букв.